# $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}, 2\pi $ periodic. Prove: if $f(x)=0$ for every $x$ around $x_0$ so $S_nf(x_0) \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ $2\pi$ periodic , Riemann integrable in $[0, 2\pi]$.
I need to prove that if $f(x)=0$ for every $x$ around $x_0$ so $S_nf(x_0) \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$.

We define $S_nf(x_0)=\sum_{-n}^{n}\hat f(n)e^{inx_o}$ and $\hat f(n)=<f,e^{inx}>=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(t)dt$, so I can't really see what makes the series 0 when n tends to infinity since $\hat f(n)$ does not depend on $x_0$ or other $x$'s around it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of theorem 8.14 in Rudin's 'Principles of Mathematical Analysis' and is actually made explicit in a corollary stated in the same section. (It's formulated there for $f:[-\pi,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, but that's just the same).

Comment: Thanks, but he does not prove it either.. How can I use the lipschitz theorem for proving that?

Comment: @Jozef ? - in my copy is a proof, if I recall correctly. I'll check when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

For the favor of people who will be interested for an answer to this question:

According to Dirichlet theorem: $f$ applies Lipshcitz conditions in $x_0$, it is Differentiable and $f'(x_0)=0$ so there's a pointwise convergent to the average  of the limits in both sides, which is $f(x_0)=0$.

Another way to look at it is just by the theorem says that $||S_nF(x)-F(x)|| \to 0$.

Comment: According to your assumption $f(x) = 0$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$. That is, there is a $\delta$-neighbourhood of $x_0$ where $f$ is $0$. So $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0 $ in that neighbourhood, which trivially implies that the hypothesis of the theorem is true. There is no need to refer to a Dirichlet theorem here, your question is solved by an immediate application of theorem 8.14 in Rudin (for which a proof is supplied in my copy).

Comment: A proof for the theorem itself or the the this immediate application?

Comment: A proof for the theorem. As explained in my comment, the corrolary is an _absolutely trivial_ consequence of the theorem. Just check the hypothesis.